# Remove escaping of quotes with Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: iphone, asp.net, ios, wcf, json

I have a WCF service. URL is: http://iphone.clickcelltest.com/EduLink.svc/GetLevel

Methods have following attribute:

```
[WebGet(ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
```

I get Data from Database and then in Collection/List of classes.
I use Newtonsoft.Json DLL to convert the collection to json string. It does it very well but i need to send this to iPhone.

But, i get unnecessary escaping of quotes. I understand the reason why it is happening.

But, is there a way to avoid it

So, how can i change the current result:

```
"{\"Object\":[{\"LevelID\":4,\"LevelName\":\"Level A\"}]}"
```

To

```
{"Object":[{"LevelID":4,"LevelName":"Level A"}]}
```

Let me know if more clarity is required.

Thanks much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like the result of [returning a manually JSON-serialized string](http://encosia.com/asp-net-web-services-mistake-manual-json-serialization/), which WCF is then serializing again. Rather than returning a string that you've built with Json.NET, make your service's return value match the type of data you're returning and return that data directly.

If you specifically need to use Json.NET for some reason, using an HttpHandler instead of WCF would allow you to respond at that lower level without WCF interfering.

Comment: Awesome...This actually works. I tried doing this earlier, but was doing a silly mistake. Also, i didn't want to take pain of creating my own class as a return type. Instead thought of using Newtonsoft.Json DLL to make my life easier, thinking that eventually it would be json that is returned. But, a little pain is better. By the way, @Dave i like reading your blog always. Thanks much.

Comment: @iMatoria: Thanks for the kind words. If you prefer not creating a class just for this purpose, another option (at least under ASMX; I haven't tested this in WCF) is to use IEnumerable as your return the collection without specifying the type. Coupled with using LINQ to select out a collection of anonymous types, that approach works nicely in some situations.

Comment: Ugh, typo there...  I meant to say "use IEnumerable as your return type to return the collection without specifying the type."

Answer (score 0):

Use `stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString` method in `NSString` class

```
NSString * jsonString = @"{\"Object\":[{\"LevelID\":4,\"LevelName\":\"Level A\"}]}";
NSString * filteredString = [jsonString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@""];
NSLog (@"%@",filteredString);
```

Comment: I am already doing this...But, this might be problematic if the LevelName is "Level \ 2".